# Hebrew - english layouts selction in android application

Tags: android, internationalization

What is the best way to provide the ability to switch between hebrew/english layouts in Android applications?

Is it commonly done - or usually just providing hebrew or english applications.
I know there is abikty to use localiztions - but is there Hebrew support for this?
Also my application should be for iPhone as well and I want to keep it the same.

How should do it in the code? Where to place the layouts?

Yoav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For orientation (right-to-left) you need: `android.text.Layout.Direction`

A hebrew TrueTypefont can then be called from a resource in your app by including TextView.
Instead of pushing 2 layout files you could use a class for hebrew and another for english...
or you could push the text to string values file for highest cleanliness

If it is a block of text that could be called from resource txt file (practical for prayers)
It all depends on how much text you have.

Comment: The main difference is on the layout, since for right to left it is a reflection of the left to right layout. (like having 2 buttons 1 aside the other , and should be switch if in the other layout mode)

Comment: Well there is no generic solution for this on android yet (localization of hebrew inside Android OS only works after rooting and installing the respective repository - probably this will only change in ICS). You will have to change orientation on a per element basis in your app (the button order does not abide by text direction) if you wish for it to display the button and text with intended order. It seems that for the time being it really would be more practical to splitt into 2 separate apps

Comment: Hmmm, then seperate apps - or can inflate the layout according to global application flag that indicates the language type. What do you think about that?

Comment: Yeah, those seem to be the two options at hand. Either one has its advantages & disadvantages. Good Luck!